# How can I find the domain and derivative of the function?

Tags: calculus

How can I find the domain of the following function $D(f)$

$$\int_{1/2}^{\sin(x)}e^{\arcsin t} dt$$

As well as the derivative for $ x \in (\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$

Answer (score 0):

The domain of $f(x):=\int_{1/2}^{\sin(x)}e^{\arcsin t} dt$ is $ \mathbb R$.

Define $F: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by $F(x):=\int_{1/2}^{x}e^{\arcsin t} dt$. Then we have

$$F'(x)=e^{\arcsin x} $$

(why ?).

Now we have $f(x)=F( \sin x)$. Can you proceed ?

Comment: I don't think you F'(x) is correct.

Comment: Why do you think that $F'$ is not correct ??

Comment: Apply Netwon Leinbnitz theorem we have $F'(x)=e^{arcsin(sin(x))}.cosx$ after seeing the proper domain we can edit the raised to part.

Comment: You took upper limit as x instead of sinx..

Comment: @ Archis: if $g$ is continuous and $F(x):=\int_a^x g(t) dt$, then $F'(x)=g(x)$.

Comment: I have edited the question if there are any changes related to it. But I can continue the derivation now. Thank you!